# Fitting UIWebView into UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I want to add a UIWebView into a cell. THe HTML data will change and I will call reloadData when this happens.

Problem is, the UIWebView changes nicely but I can't get the UITableViewCell to match the height properly. I've tried and failed at this solution...

When webview loads:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    int old_height = frame.size.height;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(280, 0);
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    float content_height = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue];
    frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(280, content_height + 20);
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"SIZES - %i - %i",old_height + 4,(int) frame.size.height);
    if(old_height + 4 != frame.size.height){
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Returned height for cell:

```
return webview.frame.size.height + 20;
```

After the first load the cell is not sized properly. It's hard to figure out how to do this. I need to stretch the entire content downwards to fit a cell.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a single web view in the tableview or one per cell? And does the table have additional rows?

Comment: It has 3 sections with one row each. THe middle section has the uiwebview.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

UIWebView isn’t designed to work inside another scroller (like UITableView);

And to resize the cell you should use either `UITableView.rowHeight` property or the following `UITableViewDelegate` method :

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

And by the way, [UITableView reloadData] is normally a bad decision for updating the table.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't answer my question. You showed my the method I'm already using and didn't show me how to change the heights correctly.

Comment: you can call [table beginUpdates]; [table endUpdates]; to force the row height calculation.

Answer (score 13):

Ran into this same issue and here's how I solved it.

From what I can tell UIWebView won't calculate its height properly until it's added superview that's rooted to a window.  So what I did is 1) create the WebView with an alpha of 0, then 2) add it to the view of my UIViewController, and then 3) reparent it to my UITableViewCell once its loaded and set the alpha to 1.  Here's what my webViewDidFinishLoad looks like.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size.height += 20.0f; // additional padding to push it off the bottom edge
    webView.frame = frame;

    webView.delegate = nil;

    UITableViewCell *cell =[_cells objectAtIndex:webView.tag];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[_loadingWebView autorelease]];
    cell.contentView.frame = frame;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];

    webView.alpha = 1.0f;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:webView.tag]];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // Storing the currently loading webView in case I need to clean it up
    // before it finishes loading.
    _loadingWebView = nil;
}
```

In my case, I'm not reusing my table view cells and I have one row per web view per section, so adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Can somebody translate it to swift?

Comment: @Calvin,can you post the answer at github which is so much helpful for everyone else in swift.?Please?

Comment: @HeathBorders,if you solve it out,can you post an example using reusable tableview cell in swift?please i need help...

Comment: Calling only [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded] before doing the webview calculation works for me with my current setup. I am preloading the cell in order to get the height prior to the cell being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *htmlStr = Your html text;
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
CGFloat htmlHight = CGRectGetHeight(rect);
```